# C# Foreach XPathNavigator faz add dos mesmos valores

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho xml recursivo, quero adicionar os valores do xml para context mas no exemplo do xml ele adiciona certo as EmpresaClientes mas quando chega para adicionar Funcionarios, ele adiciona somente os valores do primeiro elemento do Funcionario. E existe 4 Funcionarios e acaba fazendo 4 add mas com os mesmos valores do primeiro elemento em Funcionarios.

Acredito que estou errando no Xpath do Funcionarios porque somente no XPath do Funcionarios tem que colocar ele com caminho dos outros nodes. Se não colar, ele retorna null.

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(directoryTemp + "/" + wNomeArquivo);
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator xnEmpresaCliente = navigator.Select("/EmpresaLicenca/LSTEmpresaCliente/EmpresaClientes");
XPathNodeIterator xnFuncionarios = navigator.Select("/EmpresaLicenca/LSTEmpresaCliente/EmpresaClientes/LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios");
XPathNodeIterator xnDependentes = navigator.Select("/EmpresaLicenca/LSTEmpresaCliente/EmpresaClientes/LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/LSTDependentes/Dependentes");
XPathNodeIterator xnEnderecos = navigator.Select("/EmpresaLicenca/LSTEmpresaCliente/EmpresaClientes/LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/LSTEnderecos/Endereco");
XPathNodeIterator xnContatos = navigator.Select("/EmpresaLicenca/LSTEmpresaCliente/EmpresaClientes/LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/LSTContatos/Telefone");
XPathNodeIterator xnMovimentacao = navigator.Select("/EmpresaLicenca/LSTEmpresaCliente/EmpresaClientes/LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/LSTMovimentacaoFuncionarios/MovimentacaoFuncionarios");

List<MigracaoEmpresaCliente> lstEmpresaClientes = new List<MigracaoEmpresaCliente>();
List<MigracaoFuncionario> lstFuncionarios = new List<MigracaoFuncionario>();
List<MigracaoDependentes> lstDependentes = new List<MigracaoDependentes>();
List<MigracaoEndereco> lstEndereco = new List<MigracaoEndereco>();
List<MigracaoTelefone> lstTelefone = new List<MigracaoTelefone>();
List<C_MigracaoMovimentacaoFuncionario> lstMovimentacaoFuncionarios = new List<C_MigracaoMovimentacaoFuncionario>();

MigracaoEmpresaCliente wEmpresaCliente = new MigracaoEmpresaCliente();
MigracaoFuncionario wFuncionarios = new MigracaoFuncionario();
MigracaoDependentes wDependentes = new MigracaoDependentes();
MigracaoEndereco wEndereco = new MigracaoEndereco();
MigracaoTelefone wTelefones = new MigracaoTelefone();
C_MigracaoMovimentacaoFuncionario wMovimentacaoFuncionario = new C_MigracaoMovimentacaoFuncionario();

    foreach (XPathNavigator c in xnEmpresaCliente)
    {
        wEmpresaCliente = new MigracaoEmpresaCliente
        {
            CodigoCNAE = c.SelectSingleNode("CodigoCNAE").Value,
            CPFCNPJ = c.SelectSingleNode("CNPJ").Value,
            DataFundacao = Convert.ToDateTime(c.SelectSingleNode("DataFundacao").Value),
            IE = c.SelectSingleNode("InscricaoEstadual").Value,
            Nome = c.SelectSingleNode("NomeCliente").Value,
            NomeFantasia = c.SelectSingleNode("NomeFantasia").Value,
            MigracaoDados = wMigracaoDados,
            SequenciaMigracao = wMigracaoDados.Sequencia
        };
        lstEmpresaClientes.Add(wEmpresaCliente);
    }
    ctx.MigracaoEmpresaCliente.AddRange(lstEmpresaClientes);

    foreach (XPathNavigator f in xnFuncionarios)
    {
        wFuncionarios = new MigracaoFuncionario()
        {
            CasadoBrasileiro = Convert.ToBoolean(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/CasadoBrasileiro").Value),
            CNHCategria = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/CategoriaCNH").Value,
            CNHData1Habilitacao = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Data1Habilatacao").Value),
            CNHDataExpedicao = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataExpedicaoCNH").Value),
            CNHDataValidade = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataValidadeCNH").Value),
            CNHEstado = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/EstadoCNH").Value,
            CondicaoTrabalhadorEstrangeiro = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/CondicaoTrabalhador").Value,
            COR = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Cor").Value,
            CPFCNPJ = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/CPF").Value,
            CTPSEstado = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/EstadoCTPS").Value,
            CTPSSerie = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroSerieCTPS").Value,
            DataChegadaBrasil = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataChegada").Value),
            DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataNascimento").Value),
            EstadoCivil = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/EstadoCivil").Value,
            EstadoNascimento = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Estado").Value,
            Estrangeiro = Convert.ToBoolean(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Estrangeiro").Value),
            FilhosBrasil = Convert.ToBoolean(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/FilhosBrasil").Value),
            InformacoesFilhos = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/InformacoesFilhos").Value,
            MunicipioNascimento = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Municipio").Value,
            Nome = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Nome").Value,
            NomeMae = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NomeMae").Value,
            NomePai = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NomePai").Value,
            NomePaisNascimento = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NomePais").Value,
            NumeroCNH = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroCNH").Value,
            NumeroCTPS = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroCTPS").Value,
            NumeroOC = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroOC").Value,
            NumeroRG = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroRG").Value,
            NumeroRIC = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroRIC").Value,
            NumeroRNE = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/NumeroRNE").Value,
            OCDataExpedicao = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataExpedicaoOC").Value),
            QTDFilhos = Convert.ToInt32(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/QTDEFilhos").Value),
            OCDataValidade = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataValidadeOC").Value),
            OCOrgaoExpedicao = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/OrgaoExpedicaoOC").Value,
            RGDataExpedicao = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataExpedicaoRG").Value),
            RGOrgaoExpedicao = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/OrgaoExpedicaoRG").Value,
            RICDataExpedicao = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataExpedicaoRIC").Value),
            RICOrgaoExpedicao = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/OrgaoExpedicaoRIC").Value,
            RNEDataExpedicao = Convert.ToDateTime(f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/DataExpedicaoRNE").Value),
            RNEOrgaoExpedicao = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/OrgaoExpedicaoRNE").Value,
            Sexo = f.SelectSingleNode("//LSTFuncionarios/Funcionarios/Sexo").Value,
            MigracaoEmpresaCliente = wEmpresaCliente,
            SequenciaMigracaoEmpresa = wEmpresaCliente.Sequencia
        };
        lstFuncionarios.Add(wFuncionarios);
    }
    ctx.MigracaoFuncionario.AddRange(lstFuncionarios);

    foreach (XPathNavigator d in xnDependentes)
    {
        wDependentes = new MigracaoDependentes()
            {
                 CPF = d.SelectSingleNode("CPF").Value,
                 DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(d.SelectSingleNode("DataNascimento").Value),
                 DeducaoIR = Convert.ToBoolean(d.SelectSingleNode("DeducaoIR").Value),
                 Nome = d.SelectSingleNode("Nome").Value,
                 RecebeSalarioFamilia = Convert.ToBoolean(d.SelectSingleNode("RecebeSalarioFamilia").Value),
                 TipoDependente = d.SelectSingleNode("TipoDependente").Value,
                 MigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios,
                 SequenciaMigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios.Sequencia
             };
             lstDependentes.Add(wDependentes);
         }
         ctx.MigracaoDependentes.AddRange(lstDependentes);


         foreach (XPathNavigator e in xnEnderecos)
         {
             wEndereco = new MigracaoEndereco()
             {
                 Bairro = e.SelectSingleNode("Bairro").Value,
                 CEP = e.SelectSingleNode("CEP").Value,
                 Cidade = e.SelectSingleNode("Cidade").Value,
                 Complemento = e.SelectSingleNode("Complemento").Value,
                 Endereco = e.SelectSingleNode("Logradouro").Value,
                 Numero = e.SelectSingleNode("Numero").Value,
                 Pais = e.SelectSingleNode("Pais").Value,
                 TipoEndereco = e.SelectSingleNode("TipoEndereco").Value,
                 UF = e.SelectSingleNode("UF").Value,
                 MigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios,
                 SequenciaMigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios.Sequencia
             };
             lstEndereco.Add(wEndereco);
         }
         ctx.MigracaoEndereco.AddRange(lstEndereco);

         foreach (XPathNavigator t in xnContatos)
         {
             wTelefones = new MigracaoTelefone()
             {
                  DDD = t.SelectSingleNode("DDD").Value,
                  Descricao = t.SelectSingleNode("DescricaoContato").Value,
                  Email = t.SelectSingleNode("EMail").Value,
                  Telefone = t.SelectSingleNode("NumeroTelefone").Value,
                  TipoContato = t.SelectSingleNode("TipoContato").Value,
                  MigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios,
                  SequenciaMigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios.Sequencia
             };
             lstTelefone.Add(wTelefones);
         }
         ctx.MigracaoTelefone.AddRange(lstTelefone);


         foreach (XPathNavigator m in xnMovimentacao)
             {
                 wMovimentacaoFuncionario = new C_MigracaoMovimentacaoFuncionario()
                 {
                     Altura = Convert.ToDecimal(m.SelectSingleNode("Altura").Value),
                     Aposentado = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("Aposentado").Value),
                     BancoAgencia = m.SelectSingleNode("BancoAgencia").Value,
                     BancoConta = m.SelectSingleNode("BancoConta").Value,
                     BancoNumero = m.SelectSingleNode("BancoNumero").Value,
                     CategoriaTrabalhador = m.SelectSingleNode("CategiaTrabalhador").Value,
                     CondicaoContratacao = m.SelectSingleNode("CondicaoContratacao").Value,
                     CursoTecnico = m.SelectSingleNode("CursoTecnico").Value,
                     DataAdmissao = Convert.ToDateTime(m.SelectSingleNode("DataAdmissao").Value),
                     DataDemissao = Convert.ToDateTime(m.SelectSingleNode("DataDemissao").Value),
                     DataInclusao = Convert.ToDateTime(m.SelectSingleNode("DataInclusao").Value),
                     DeficienciaAuditiva = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("DeficienciaAuditiva").Value),
                     DeficienciaFisica = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("DeficienciaFisica").Value),
                     DeficienciaIntelectual = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("DeficienciaIntelectual").Value),
                     Deficienciamental = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("DeficienciaMental").Value),
                     DeficienciaVisual = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("DeficienciaVisual").Value),
                     DemissaoJustaCausa = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("DemissaoJustaCausa").Value),
                     DescricaoJornadaTrabalho = m.SelectSingleNode("DescricaoJornadaTrabalho").Value,
                     Dominancia = m.SelectSingleNode("Dominancia").Value,
                     Escolaridade = m.SelectSingleNode("Escolaridade").Value,
                     ItemCategoria = m.SelectSingleNode("ItemCategoria").Value,
                     MesDataBase = Convert.ToInt32(m.SelectSingleNode("MesDataBaseCategoria").Value),
                     NaturezaAtividade = m.SelectSingleNode("NaturezaAtividade").Value,
                     NomeDepartamento = m.SelectSingleNode("NomeDepartamento").Value,
                     NomeFuncao = m.SelectSingleNode("NomeFuncao").Value,
                     NumeroMatricula = m.SelectSingleNode("NumeroMatricula").Value,
                     NumeroTrabalhador = m.SelectSingleNode("NumeroTrabalhador").Value,
                     Peso = Convert.ToDecimal(m.SelectSingleNode("Peso").Value),
                     PrimeiroEmprego = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("PrimeiroEmprego").Value),
                     Reabilitado = Convert.ToBoolean(m.SelectSingleNode("Reabilitado").Value),
                     RegimeJornada = m.SelectSingleNode("RegimeJornada").Value,
                     RegimePrevidenciario = m.SelectSingleNode("RegimePrevidenciario").Value,
                     RemuneracaoDescricao = m.SelectSingleNode("DescricaoRemuneracao").Value,
                     RemuneracaoUnidadePagamento = m.SelectSingleNode("UnidadePagamento").Value,
                     Tabagista = m.SelectSingleNode("Tabagista").Value,
                     TempoJornadaTrabalho = m.SelectSingleNode("TempoJornadaTrabalho").Value,
                     TipoAdmissao = m.SelectSingleNode("TipoAdmissao").Value,
                     TipoContratacao = m.SelectSingleNode("TipoContratacao").Value,
                     TipoContratoParcial = m.SelectSingleNode("TipoContratoParcial").Value,
                     TipoContratoTrabalho = m.SelectSingleNode("TipoContratoTrabalho").Value,
                     UsoAlcool = m.SelectSingleNode("UsoAlcool").Value,
                     UsoDrograsIlicitas = m.SelectSingleNode("UsoDrogasIlicitas").Value,
                     ValorRemuneracao = Convert.ToDecimal(m.SelectSingleNode("ValorRemuneracao").Value),
                     MigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios,
                     SequenciaMigracaoFuncionario = wFuncionarios.Sequencia
                };

                lstMovimentacaoFuncionarios.Add(wMovimentacaoFuncionario);
            }

   ctx.C_MigracaoMovimentacaoFuncionario.AddRange(lstMovimentacaoFuncionarios);


   ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><EmpresaLicenca xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SequenciaFornecedor>522b2266-111111</SequenciaFornecedor><LSTEmpresaCliente><EmpresaClientes><CNPJ>66.444.555/0001-09</CNPJ><NomeCliente>Empresa Teste Cliente</NomeCliente><NomeFantasia>Fantasia Teste</NomeFantasia><InscricaoEstadual>59849849</InscricaoEstadual><DataFundacao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0922718-03:00</DataFundacao><CodigoCNAE>844844</CodigoCNAE><LSTFuncionarios><Funcionarios><CPF>222.555.554-88</CPF><Nome>Felipe da Silva</Nome><Sexo>Masculino</Sexo><EstadoCivil>Casado</EstadoCivil><Cor>Branca</Cor><Estrangeiro>false</Estrangeiro><DataChegada>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0942703-03:00</DataChegada><CondicaoTrabalhador>VistoTemporario</CondicaoTrabalhador><CasadoBrasileiro>false</CasadoBrasileiro><FilhosBrasil>false</FilhosBrasil><QTDEFilhos>2</QTDEFilhos><InformacoesFilhos>A teste</InformacoesFilhos><NomePai>Fulano</NomePai><NomeMae>Fulana</NomeMae><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0972694-03:00</DataNascimento><NomePais>Brasil</NomePais><Estado>PR</Estado><Municipio>Londrina</Municipio><NumeroRG>54484141</NumeroRG><OrgaoExpedicaoRG>SSP</OrgaoExpedicaoRG><DataExpedicaoRG>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0962696-03:00</DataExpedicaoRG><NumeroCTPS>5448484848484</NumeroCTPS><NumeroSerieCTPS>656</NumeroSerieCTPS><EstadoCTPS>PR</EstadoCTPS><NumeroRIC>4894894</NumeroRIC><OrgaoExpedicaoRIC>Orgão RIC</OrgaoExpedicaoRIC><DataExpedicaoRIC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0962696-03:00</DataExpedicaoRIC><NumeroRNE>4848484844</NumeroRNE><OrgaoExpedicaoRNE>Orgao RNE</OrgaoExpedicaoRNE><DataExpedicaoRNE>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0962696-03:00</DataExpedicaoRNE><NumeroOC>545985498458</NumeroOC><OrgaoExpedicaoOC>Orgão OC</OrgaoExpedicaoOC><DataExpedicaoOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0952693-03:00</DataExpedicaoOC><DataValidadeOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0982688-03:00</DataValidadeOC><NumeroCNH>54664564116</NumeroCNH><EstadoCNH>PR</EstadoCNH><CategoriaCNH>B</CategoriaCNH><DataExpedicaoCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0952693-03:00</DataExpedicaoCNH><DataValidadeCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0972694-03:00</DataValidadeCNH><Data1Habilatacao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.0942703-03:00</Data1Habilatacao><LSTMovimentacaoFuncionarios><MovimentacaoFuncionarios><NumeroTrabalhador>5489</NumeroTrabalhador><TempoJornadaTrabalho>6</TempoJornadaTrabalho><DescricaoJornadaTrabalho>T</DescricaoJornadaTrabalho><TipoContratoParcial>1</TipoContratoParcial><NomeFuncao>Analista</NomeFuncao><NomeDepartamento>RH</NomeDepartamento><NumeroMatricula>44448</NumeroMatricula><TipoContratacao>CLT</TipoContratacao><Aposentado>false</Aposentado><PrimeiroEmprego>false</PrimeiroEmprego><RegimePrevidenciario>RGPS</RegimePrevidenciario><CategiaTrabalhador>AgentePublico</CategiaTrabalhador><ItemCategoria>AgentePolitico</ItemCategoria><DataAdmissao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.1052644-03:00</DataAdmissao><TipoAdmissao>1</TipoAdmissao><CondicaoContratacao>1</CondicaoContratacao><RegimeJornada>44</RegimeJornada><NaturezaAtividade>1</NaturezaAtividade><MesDataBaseCategoria>3</MesDataBaseCategoria><DataDemissao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.1052644-03:00</DataDemissao><DemissaoJustaCausa>false</DemissaoJustaCausa><TipoContratoTrabalho>1</TipoContratoTrabalho><ValorRemuneracao>555.55</ValorRemuneracao><UnidadePagamento>1</UnidadePagamento><DescricaoRemuneracao>Salario</DescricaoRemuneracao><Escolaridade>FundamentalCompleto</Escolaridade><CursoTecnico>Tecnico</CursoTecnico><BancoNumero>77</BancoNumero><BancoAgencia>111</BancoAgencia><BancoConta>55555</BancoConta><Dominancia>Domi</Dominancia><Peso>85.55</Peso><Altura>1.80</Altura><Tabagista>Sim</Tabagista><UsoAlcool>Sim</UsoAlcool><UsoDrogasIlicitas>Não</UsoDrogasIlicitas><DeficienciaFisica>false</DeficienciaFisica><DeficienciaVisual>false</DeficienciaVisual><DeficienciaAuditiva>false</DeficienciaAuditiva><DeficienciaMental>false</DeficienciaMental><DeficienciaIntelectual>false</DeficienciaIntelectual><Reabilitado>false</Reabilitado><DataInclusao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.1052644-03:00</DataInclusao></MovimentacaoFuncionarios></LSTMovimentacaoFuncionarios><LSTDependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 1</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.1012676-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 2</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.1012676-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes></LSTDependentes><LSTEnderecos><Endereco><TipoEndereco>Rua</TipoEndereco><CEP>54884-155</CEP><Logradouro>Rua Teste</Logradouro><Numero>5555</Numero><Complemento>apt</Complemento><Bairro>Jardim</Bairro><Cidade>Londrina</Cidade><UF>PR</UF><Pais>Brasil</Pais></Endereco></LSTEnderecos><LSTContatos><Telefone><TipoContato>1</TipoContato><DDD>43</DDD><NumeroTelefone>5641545</NumeroTelefone><EMail>Asdd@dff.com</EMail><DescricaoContato>A</DescricaoContato></Telefone></LSTContatos></Funcionarios><Funcionarios><CPF>333.555.668-89</CPF><Nome>Luis Fellipe</Nome><Sexo>Masculino</Sexo><EstadoCivil>Solteiro</EstadoCivil><Cor>Branca</Cor><Estrangeiro>false</Estrangeiro><DataChegada>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataChegada><CondicaoTrabalhador>VistoPermanente</CondicaoTrabalhador><CasadoBrasileiro>false</CasadoBrasileiro><FilhosBrasil>false</FilhosBrasil><QTDEFilhos>2</QTDEFilhos><InformacoesFilhos>A teste</InformacoesFilhos><NomePai>Fulano</NomePai><NomeMae>Fulana</NomeMae><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><NomePais>Brasil</NomePais><Estado>PR</Estado><Municipio>Londrina</Municipio><NumeroRG>54484141</NumeroRG><OrgaoExpedicaoRG>SSP</OrgaoExpedicaoRG><DataExpedicaoRG>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRG><NumeroCTPS>5448484848484</NumeroCTPS><NumeroSerieCTPS>656</NumeroSerieCTPS><EstadoCTPS>PR</EstadoCTPS><NumeroRIC>4894894</NumeroRIC><OrgaoExpedicaoRIC>Orgão RIC</OrgaoExpedicaoRIC><DataExpedicaoRIC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRIC><NumeroRNE>4848484844</NumeroRNE><OrgaoExpedicaoRNE>Orgao RNE</OrgaoExpedicaoRNE><DataExpedicaoRNE>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRNE><NumeroOC>545985498458</NumeroOC><OrgaoExpedicaoOC>Orgão OC</OrgaoExpedicaoOC><DataExpedicaoOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoOC><DataValidadeOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataValidadeOC><NumeroCNH>54664564116</NumeroCNH><EstadoCNH>PR</EstadoCNH><DataExpedicaoCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoCNH><DataValidadeCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataValidadeCNH><Data1Habilatacao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</Data1Habilatacao><LSTDependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 1</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 2</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes></LSTDependentes><LSTEnderecos><Endereco><TipoEndereco>Rua</TipoEndereco><CEP>54884-155</CEP><Logradouro>Rua Teste</Logradouro><Numero>5555</Numero><Complemento>apt</Complemento><Bairro>Jardim</Bairro><Cidade>Londrina</Cidade><UF>PR</UF><Pais>Brasil</Pais></Endereco></LSTEnderecos><LSTContatos><Telefone><TipoContato>1</TipoContato><DDD>43</DDD><NumeroTelefone>5641545</NumeroTelefone><EMail>Asdd@dff.com</EMail><DescricaoContato>A</DescricaoContato></Telefone></LSTContatos></Funcionarios><Funcionarios><CPF>444.555.554-88</CPF><Nome>João da Silva</Nome><Sexo>Masculino</Sexo><EstadoCivil>Casado</EstadoCivil><Cor>Branca</Cor><Estrangeiro>false</Estrangeiro><DataChegada>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataChegada><CondicaoTrabalhador>VistoPermanente</CondicaoTrabalhador><CasadoBrasileiro>false</CasadoBrasileiro><FilhosBrasil>false</FilhosBrasil><QTDEFilhos>2</QTDEFilhos><InformacoesFilhos>A teste</InformacoesFilhos><NomePai>Fulano</NomePai><NomeMae>Fulana</NomeMae><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><NomePais>Brasil</NomePais><Estado>PR</Estado><Municipio>Londrina</Municipio><NumeroRG>54484141</NumeroRG><OrgaoExpedicaoRG>SSP</OrgaoExpedicaoRG><DataExpedicaoRG>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRG><NumeroCTPS>5448484848484</NumeroCTPS><NumeroSerieCTPS>656</NumeroSerieCTPS><EstadoCTPS>PR</EstadoCTPS><NumeroRIC>4894894</NumeroRIC><OrgaoExpedicaoRIC>Orgão RIC</OrgaoExpedicaoRIC><DataExpedicaoRIC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRIC><NumeroRNE>4848484844</NumeroRNE><OrgaoExpedicaoRNE>Orgao RNE</OrgaoExpedicaoRNE><DataExpedicaoRNE>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRNE><NumeroOC>545985498458</NumeroOC><OrgaoExpedicaoOC>Orgão OC</OrgaoExpedicaoOC><DataExpedicaoOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoOC><DataValidadeOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataValidadeOC><NumeroCNH>54664564116</NumeroCNH><EstadoCNH>PR</EstadoCNH><DataExpedicaoCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoCNH><DataValidadeCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataValidadeCNH><Data1Habilatacao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</Data1Habilatacao><LSTDependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 1</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 2</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes></LSTDependentes><LSTEnderecos><Endereco><TipoEndereco>Rua</TipoEndereco><CEP>54884-155</CEP><Logradouro>Rua Teste</Logradouro><Numero>5555</Numero><Complemento>apt</Complemento><Bairro>Jardim</Bairro><Cidade>Londrina</Cidade><UF>PR</UF><Pais>Brasil</Pais></Endereco></LSTEnderecos><LSTContatos><Telefone><TipoContato>1</TipoContato><DDD>43</DDD><NumeroTelefone>5641545</NumeroTelefone><EMail>Asdd@dff.com</EMail><DescricaoContato>A</DescricaoContato></Telefone></LSTContatos></Funcionarios></LSTFuncionarios></EmpresaClientes><EmpresaClientes><CNPJ>66.444.555/0001-09</CNPJ><NomeCliente>Empresa Cliente</NomeCliente><NomeFantasia>Fantasia Teste</NomeFantasia><InscricaoEstadual>59849849</InscricaoEstadual><DataFundacao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataFundacao><CodigoCNAE>844844</CodigoCNAE><LSTFuncionarios><Funcionarios><CPF>555.555.554-88</CPF><Nome>Jose da Silva</Nome><Sexo>Masculino</Sexo><EstadoCivil>Casado</EstadoCivil><Cor>Branca</Cor><Estrangeiro>false</Estrangeiro><DataChegada>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataChegada><CondicaoTrabalhador>VistoTemporario</CondicaoTrabalhador><CasadoBrasileiro>false</CasadoBrasileiro><FilhosBrasil>false</FilhosBrasil><QTDEFilhos>2</QTDEFilhos><InformacoesFilhos>A teste</InformacoesFilhos><NomePai>Fulano</NomePai><NomeMae>Fulana</NomeMae><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><NomePais>Brasil</NomePais><Estado>PR</Estado><Municipio>Londrina</Municipio><NumeroRG>54484141</NumeroRG><OrgaoExpedicaoRG>SSP</OrgaoExpedicaoRG><DataExpedicaoRG>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRG><NumeroCTPS>5448484848484</NumeroCTPS><NumeroSerieCTPS>656</NumeroSerieCTPS><EstadoCTPS>PR</EstadoCTPS><NumeroRIC>4894894</NumeroRIC><OrgaoExpedicaoRIC>Orgão RIC</OrgaoExpedicaoRIC><DataExpedicaoRIC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRIC><NumeroRNE>4848484844</NumeroRNE><OrgaoExpedicaoRNE>Orgao RNE</OrgaoExpedicaoRNE><DataExpedicaoRNE>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoRNE><NumeroOC>545985498458</NumeroOC><OrgaoExpedicaoOC>Orgão OC</OrgaoExpedicaoOC><DataExpedicaoOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoOC><DataValidadeOC>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataValidadeOC><NumeroCNH>54664564116</NumeroCNH><EstadoCNH>PR</EstadoCNH><CategoriaCNH>B</CategoriaCNH><DataExpedicaoCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataExpedicaoCNH><DataValidadeCNH>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataValidadeCNH><Data1Habilatacao>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</Data1Habilatacao><LSTDependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 1</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes><Dependentes><CPF>878844554</CPF><Nome>Filho 2</Nome><DataNascimento>2018-09-24T09:34:39.110262-03:00</DataNascimento><TipoDependente>Filho</TipoDependente><DeducaoIR>true</DeducaoIR><RecebeSalarioFamilia>false</RecebeSalarioFamilia></Dependentes></LSTDependentes><LSTEnderecos><Endereco><TipoEndereco>Rua</TipoEndereco><CEP>54884-155</CEP><Logradouro>Rua Teste</Logradouro><Numero>5555</Numero><Complemento>apt</Complemento><Bairro>Jardim</Bairro><Cidade>Londrina</Cidade><UF>PR</UF><Pais>Brasil</Pais></Endereco></LSTEnderecos><LSTContatos><Telefone><TipoContato>1</TipoContato><DDD>43</DDD><NumeroTelefone>5641545</NumeroTelefone><EMail>Asdd@dff.com</EMail><DescricaoContato>A</DescricaoContato></Telefone></LSTContatos></Funcionarios></LSTFuncionarios></EmpresaClientes></LSTEmpresaCliente></EmpresaLicenca>
```